# Angular CLI and Bamboo: Getting Bamboo variables

Tags: angular, angular-cli

We just converted our Angular application to CLI from a popular webpack seed.

We are setting the application's version number in Bamboo. This version number along with other variables are exposed in the environment vars. In the past we used process.env and webpack.DefinePlugin to capture these variables and set them in the app at build time.

So, it looked something like this:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env' : {
           VERSION: JSON.stringify((process.env.bamboo_versionNumber || '') + '.' + 
                                   (process.env.bamboo_buildNumber || '') + 
                                   (process.env.bamboo_buildType || ''))
        }
    })
```

and later in the the TS code:

```
this.appVersion = process.env.VERSION;
```

This allowed us to display to the user the version number along with any other information from Bamboo...

There appears to be no way to configure Webpack with the CLI...

How can we achieve this using Angular CLI? Is there a way to pass environment variables that are exposed from Bamboo into our application at build time?

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve for this?